# cakephp : separate database access for admin users

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been using cakephp for creating web application. In my current project there are two database users one for admin another for site users, how can I configure cakephp so that the admin can login to the site with more database operations power ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. Sometimes, it's better having permissions handled in your application layer than the database layer. However, if you *really, really* want to have that extra layer of security in your database as well, then you should set up multiple database connections:

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'normaluser',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db',
    'prefix' => '',
);

var $admin = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'adminuser',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

You can then use `$this->ModelName->setDataSource('admin')` if the user is in the admin section, or whatever condition that you might impose.

I would suggest that you look at the `admin_` prefix routing. CakePHP lets you handle admin powers quite easily. [Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing) Additionally, you can add a field in your users table to indicate the role of the user, and check that against the current prefix.

Answer (score 0):

the most robust solution will likely be setting up Access Control Lists(ACLs).  This will allow you to delegate permissions based on a user role that you designate.

For example admin has a group_id of 1, and users have a group_id of 2.  Then you can allow admins to have access to certain operations within your web app.

Here's the cake documentation on this feature.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists